# How do i use an API on the P5js library?

Tags: javascript, api, p5.js, weather

I've been working on the p5js library and i'm trying to use an API to get access to weather data for my project, but the editor keeps throwing an error and I don't know why
Here's my code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400); 
  let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=e7402cc176aacd446829a856f2723b57&units=metric'
  loadJSON(url,gotData)
}

function gotData(data){
  print(data);  
}

function draw(){
}
```

Can someone help point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please look at your post, and then edit it to use [proper markup](/markdown). But in addition to that, please also [include all the details](/help/how-to-ask): which editor? what error? what have you already tried in terms of debugging? Remember that Stackoverflow is not a general help forum, and you are expected to fully describe the problem so that others can both help you figure things out, _and_ so that future visitors can determine from your post whether that's their problem too, and so whether or not the answer this might get will help them, too.

Answer (score 3):

You should post the errors you're getting.
(Since you were already using the p5.js editor you could also share a link so it's easier to for everyone else to replicate your issue)

I've just tried your code in the p5 web editor and I'm getting this error in the browser's JS Console:

```
p5.js:84555 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://editor.p5js.org/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=e7402cc176aacd446829a856f2723b57&units=metric'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Sometimes errors can be cryptic, but in this case it's pretty straight forward:

- p5.js is loaded from an HTTPS domain (`https://editor.p5js.org`)
- the weather API is accessed via HTTP(unsecure) (`http://api.openweathermap.org/...etc.`)
- Ideally you'd load both via HTTPS (and the Weather API supports HTTPS).

This is makes the solution as simple as adding a single 's' :)
(from `http://` to `https://` when accessing the Weather API)

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400); 
  let url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=e7402cc176aacd446829a856f2723b57&units=metric'
  loadJSON(url,gotData)
}

function gotData(data){
  print(data);  
}

function draw(){
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```